# how do i get numbers that can be expressed in the form (3^a)*(5^b)*(7^c)

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm

Bee numbers are numbers that can be expressed in the form `(3^a)*(5^b)*(7^c)`. where `a`, `b` and `c` are positive integers.

Task:

> Write a function that takes in a positive integer n and returns the nth smallest Bee number
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> bNumber(1)===1//(3^0)*(5^0)*(7^0)
>
> bNumber(2)===3//(3^1)*(5^0)*(7^0)
>
> bNumber(3)===5//(3^0)*(5^1)*(7^0)
>
> bNumber(4)===7//(3^0)*(5^0)*(7^1)
>
> bNumber(100)===33075//(3^3)*(5^2)*(7^2)
> ```

My attempt:

```
let bNumber = (n) => {
    var beenumbers = []
    var a = 0
    var b = 0
    var c = 0
    while (beenumbers.length <= n) {
        var beeSchema = Math.pow(3,a)*Math.pow(5,b)*Math.pow(7,c);
        var beeArray = [] 
        var bee = Math.min((Math.pow(3, a + 1) * Math.pow(5, b) * Math.pow(7, c)),
            (Math.pow(3, a) * Math.pow(5, b + 1) * Math.pow(7, c)), (Math.pow(3, a) * Math.pow(5, b) * Math.pow(7, c + 1)))
        beenumbers.push(bee);
    }
    return beenumbers;

}
```

The problem for me has to perfect the system that would successfully validate what increment of 1 in `a`, `b` or `c` would give the next bee number. I used `Math.min` to get the smallest result in an increment of `a`, `b` or `c` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: constraints on N?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not really clear on what a bee number is. What is bee number 5? It could go one of a few ways based on 1-4, and bee number 100 is sort of too far out to make it obvious.

Comment: Your example is very confusing, it doesn't make sense: bNumber(1)===1//(3^0)*(5^0)*(7^0)

Comment: How do you define the umpteenth number of bees with the expression depending on a, b and c? For example, what would be the first and second bee numbers?

Comment: @AksJacoves  for example the 3rd bnumber is 5 ie bnumber(3) == 5 and 5 can be represented in the form (3^a)*(5^b)*(7^c) by (3^0)*(5^1)*(7^0).

Comment: Ok, understand.

Comment: Look at k-smooth numbers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344313/generating-ascending-sequence-2p3q

Comment: Could it be that you forgot considering that any number ```x^0 = 1``` for ```x >= 0``` ? This means that your examples are wrong.

Comment: Should "where a, b and c are positive integers" actually say "where a, b and c are non-negative integers?" 0 is not a positive integer, so your examples don't match your definition.